# How to interpret certain aspects of dhcpd logs

Tags: linux, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have a DHCP server running on RHEL 6.6. I understand the process (somewhat) involving how the conversation goes from a protocol standpoint to set up a lease. 1 - The DHCPDISCOVER message. 2- The DHCPOFFER, 3- the DHCPREQUEST, and 4- The DHCPACK. However what does it mean when you see the following activity in a log? Notice how there is continued activity on the IP long after the initial DHCPOFFER took place. What is going on here? Is this just the client renewing/requesting the same IP therefore no DHCPDISCOVER OR DHCPOFFER needs to take place?

```
Dec  7 00:02:17 test dhcpd: DHCPACK on 123.123.123.123 to 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
Dec  8 00:02:27 test dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 123.123.123.123 from 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
Dec  8 00:02:27 test dhcpd: DHCPACK on 123.123.123.123 to 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
Dec  9 00:02:35 test dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 123.123.123.123 from 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
Dec  9 00:02:35 test dhcpd: DHCPACK on 123.123.123.123 to 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
Dec 10 00:02:41 test dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 123.123.123.123 from 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
Dec 10 00:02:41 test dhcpd: DHCPACK on 123.123.123.123 to 00:0f:94:50:f5:60 via em0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a request for extension of the lease don't need the DISCOVER/OFFER part.